# data convert to symbolic language

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql Server I join two query using *UNION* and my "Address" column has *nText* datatype so it's have an issue in Distinct. So i have to convert Address column *nText* to *varchar* but in output i got symbolic data in Adress. Actual data is in our local 'Gujarati' Language.

Comment: instead of varchar change to nvarchar and check

Comment: u r welcome @vishalpatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar:` Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. The database collation determines which code page the data is stored using.

`nvarchar:` Variable-length Unicode character data. Dependent on the database collation for comparisons.

so change your type `varchar` to `nvarchar` it will sort your issue..

Same issue face by me during storing arabic charachters

Answer (score 1):

Please use "nvarchar" instead of "varchar"

Answer (score 1):

The `n` in `ntext` basically means "Unicode." In order to maintain those characters, you need to cast to another *Unicode* type.

The Unicode equivalent to `varchar` is `nvarchar`, so your query might end up looking like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [Address]) 
FROM YourTable
```